# How do you delete a many to many association in ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

It's not clear to me how to delete a many to many association in Ecto. I do not want to delete the associated structures, just the relationship.

My first attempt was to find the association in join_through table and delete it, but there is no primary key so `Repo.delete` fails.

Comment: you can define a **:on_delete** option that specifies which action should be performed on associations when the parent is deleted: [Ecto docs has_many/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3)

Comment: I don't want to delete the parent. I want to delete the association itself

Comment: Have you tried [`Repo.delete_all/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:delete_all/2) with a query on the join table and both foreign keys?

Comment: That worked Martin. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Repo.delete_all/2` with a query on the join table and both foreign keys.

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:delete_all/2

Comment: An example: `Repo.delete_all(from r in "teams_users", where: r.team_id == ^team.id, select: [r.id, r.team_id, r.user_id])`